# How to hide or delete the zero in my bash script?

Tags: regex, bash, variables, math, logic

This is my script:

```
echo -n "number 1 :";
read bil1
echo -n "number 2 :";
read bil2
multiple=$(echo $bil1*$bil2 |bc -l |sed -e 's/^\./0./' -e 's/^-\./-0./');
echo " Your result : $bil1 * $bil2 = $multiple ";
```

If I input `9.5` for `$bil1` and `300` for `$bil2`, the result is `2850.0`.

I want the result:

```
Your result : 9.5 * 300 = 2850
```

How do I hide or delete the zero at the end of the result? I.e. show only `2850` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following part to your sed command (at the end):

```
-e 's/\.0*$//'
```

(Delete a dot followed by arbitrarily many zeroes at the end by nothing.)

By the way, you better replace `echo $bil1*$bil2` by `echo "$bil1*$bil2"`, otherwise you may get strange effects depending on the contents of the current directory.

Comment: @Vash2593 Which script are you looking at?

Comment: @Vash2593 No, the `$bil1*$bil2` in the fifth line is currently not quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the normal, floating-point output of `bc` to the variable, then trim it using parameter expansion:

```
multiple=$(echo "$bil1*$bil2" | bc -l)
# Not POSIX, unfortunately
shopt -s extglob
multiple=${multiple%.+(0)}
echo " Your result : $bil1 * $bil2 = $multiple "
```

A POSIX solution is to let `printf` do the work

```
multiple=$(echo "$bil1*$bil2" | bc -l)
printf " Your result : %1.1f * %d = %1.0f\n" $bil1 $bil2 $multiple
```

Answer (score 1):

use bash's builtin `printf` to control the output

```
$ bil1=9.5; bil2=300; printf "%.0f\n" $(bc -l <<< "$bil1 * $bil2")
2850
```

Comment: If one wants to round to the next integer, that's probably the best solution; if one only wants to delete redundant _zeroes_ (but not other digits) after the period, it does not work.